# What is the relationship between the sum of a graph's vertices and its regions?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a problem that claims that because a certain simple, connected planar graph $G$ has no simple cycles of length 4 or less, the sum of the degrees of the vertices must be greater than or equal to $5r$, where $r$ is the number of regions. Why is this?

Comment: Do you mean "If a simple connected planar graph has no simple cycles of length 4 or less..." instead? Since it seems that a simple connected planar graph can have lots of simple cycles of length 4 or less.

Comment: You're right, I meant "because a certain graph $G$ has..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the vertex-region incidences in two ways:

- Each vertex $v$ is incident not only with $\deg(v)$ edges, but also with $\deg r$ regions between these.
- Each region is incident with as many vertices as the length of its bounding cycle states. By assumption, this cycle has length $\ge 5$.

From the first point, the total number of incidences is $\sum_v \deg(v)$, from the second point it is $\ge 5r$